# UIContextualAction delete row issue. UIContextualAction's menu overlaps the cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicontextualaction

I have two UIContextualActions which should delete rows from the table after completion. I faced the following intermittent issue:
If I apply this actions very fast one by one, then the first action works fine, but when I call UIContextualAction's menu for the second time it overlaps the cell. In the third time, it is not possible to call UIContextualAction's menu until tableView is scrolled.  [Here the short video](https://youtu.be/P0IOIQlYqpk).

Please find below the piece of code

```
    //MARK: Swipe actions
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let deleteAction = self.contextualDeleteAction(forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    let markAsReadAction = self.contextualMarkAsReadAction(forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    let markAsUnreadAction = self.contextualMarkAsUnreadAction(forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    let swipeConfig = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [
        isArchiveModeEnabled ? markAsUnreadAction : markAsReadAction,
        deleteAction
        ])

    swipeConfig.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false

    return swipeConfig
}

func contextualMarkAsUnreadAction(forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "") { _, _, completion in
        let index = indexPath.row

        if let article = self.getSelectedArticleByIndex(index) {
            self.articlesManager.restore(article: article)
            self.refreshDataSource()
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            self.tableView.isEditing = false //seems like it helps to fix visual bug when the action is left on blank space
            completion(true)
        }
    }

    action.backgroundColor =  UIColor(patternImage: swipeActinImages.markAsUnread)

    return action
}
```

refreshDataSource function do the following:

```
 private func refreshDataSource() {
    articles = isArchiveModeEnabled ? dataController.getArchivedArticles() : dataController.getUnreadArticles()
}    

private func reloadTableData() {
    if dataController.getActiveUser() != nil {
        refreshDataSource()
        introView?.isHidden = articles.count != 0 || isArchiveModeEnabled
        tableView.isScrollEnabled = (introView?.isHidden)!

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate any help

**UPDATE**

So I solved it. I've replaced UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "") to UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "") and don't update datasource manualy anymore. Completion(true) do all needed manipulation with cell and table
automaticaly.

The final code is

```
    func contextualMarkAsUnreadAction(forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "") { _, _, completion in
        let index = indexPath.row

        if let article = self.getSelectedArticleByIndex(index) {
            self.articlesManager.restore(article: article)
            //self.refreshDataSource()
            completion(true)
        } else {
            completion(false)
        }
    }

    action.backgroundColor =  UIColor(patternImage: swipeActinImages.markAsUnread)

    return action
}
```